# I'm getting a (TypeError jQuery) using jquery keydown events on the document, its causing lots of events to fire rather than just the selected one

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I'm using a plugin called [Vex](http://github.hubspot.com/vex/) which is used for dialogs.

Vex works by creating dialogs on the fly using JS so the html doesn't exists on the page so for that reason, I used the following code. The problem with this is that cause the keydown event is fired on the document, it's causing all keydown events to fire even though I have put the selector in '.test1'

```
$(document).keydown('.test1', function(e) {
    //do stuff here
});
```

Please see the fiddle [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/1eddy87/6npgsxcd/) (see the errors logged in the console)

Any ideas how to stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using .on() if you want to **bind dynamic content**.

```
$(document).on("keydown", ".test1", function(e){
    //do stuff here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, Legend!